# Show that $ \text{Tr} ( XYXZ) = \text{Tr}(XY) \text{Tr}(XZ) - \text{Tr}( YZ^{-1} ) $

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, quaternions

For $X,Y,Z \in \text{SL}_2(\mathbb{C})$ we have the following identities for $2 \times 2$ matrices: 
$$ \text{Tr} \big( XYXZ\big) = \text{Tr}\big(XY\big) \text{Tr}\big(XZ\big) - \text{Tr}\big( YZ^{-1} \big) \tag{$\ast$}$$
These are stated without proof, but they do give the following hint: basically the [Cayley-Hamilton identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem)

$$ X^2 = \text{Tr}(X)\, X -I$$

and many other interesting formulas on that page.

Underlying all of that... are all these $2 \times 2$ matrix identities fundamentally different from things like $\text{Tr}(I) = 2$ and $\text{Tr}(XY) = \text{Tr}(YX) $.  This equation is taken from a book on [quaternions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions).

---

Here are some thought's using Dirac's [bra-ket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bra%E2%80%93ket_notation) notation (rather than indices):

\begin{eqnarray*} \text{Tr}(XY) &=& \langle 1 | XY | 1 \rangle + \langle 2 | XY | 2 \rangle \\ \\
&=& 
\Big( \langle 1 | X | 1 \rangle \langle 1 | Y | 1 \rangle +
\langle 1 | X | 2 \rangle \langle 2 | Y | 1 \rangle \Big) +
\Big( \langle 2 | X | 1 \rangle \langle 1 | Y | 2 \rangle +
\langle 2 | X | 2 \rangle \langle 2 | Y | 2 \rangle \Big) \\ \\
&=& 
\Big( \langle 1 | X | 1 \rangle \langle 1 | Y | 1 \rangle +
\langle 2 | X | 1 \rangle \langle 1 | Y | 2 \rangle \Big) +
\Big( \langle 1 | X | 2 \rangle \langle 2 | Y | 1 \rangle +
\langle 2 | X | 2 \rangle \langle 2 | Y | 2 \rangle \Big) \\ \\
&=& \text{Tr}(YX) \end{eqnarray*}

Even an index proof could be somewhat informative here.

Comment: Take $X$ and $Z$ to be the identity matrix; then you will get $\text{Tr}(Y)=2$ for all $Y\in\text{SL}_2(\mathbb{C})$.  This doesn't seem correct.

Comment: @Batominovski corrected

Comment: You haven't corrected the title.  Plus, Cayley-Hamilton should imply $X^2=\text{Tr}(X)\,X-1$, right?  (The constant term shouldn't be $-2$.)

Comment: Since we have a $2 \times 2$ matrix, $\text{Tr}(I_{2 \times 2}) = 2$.

Comment: The constant term should be $-\text{det}(X)=-1$.

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

First note that
$$ \text{Tr} \big( XYXZ\big) =\text{Tr} \big( XZXY\big) =\text{Tr} \big( ZXZXYZ^{-1}\big) =\text{Tr} \big( (ZX)^2YZ^{-1}\big). $$
By using 
$$ X^2 = \text{Tr}(X)\, X -I$$
one has
\begin{eqnarray}
\text{Tr} \big( XYXZ\big)&=&\text{Tr} \big( (ZX)^2YZ^{-1}\big)\\
&=&\text{Tr} \big( (\text{Tr}(ZX)ZX-I)YZ^{-1}\big)\\
&=&\text{Tr} \big(\text{Tr}(ZX)ZXYZ^{-1}-YZ^{-1}\big)\\
&=&\text{Tr}(ZX)\text{Tr} \big(ZXYZ^{-1}\big)-\text{Tr}\big(YZ^{-1}\big)\\
&=&\text{Tr}(ZX)\text{Tr} \big(XY\big)-\text{Tr}\big(YZ^{-1}\big)\\
&=&\text{Tr}(XY)\text{Tr} \big(XZ\big)-\text{Tr}\big(YZ^{-1}\big).
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 1):

The claim works in any field.  Hence, I shall prove that
$$\text{Tr}(XYXZ)=\text{Tr}(XY)\,\text{Tr}(XZ)-\text{Tr}(YZ^{-1})$$
for all $X,Y,Z\in\text{SL}_2(\mathbb{K})$ for an arbitrary field $\mathbb{K}$.  For convenience, $0$ also denotes the $2$-by-$2$ zero matrix and $I$ is the $2$-by-$2$ identity matrix.

We have by the Cayley-Hamilton Theorem that $$T^2-\text{Tr}(T)\,T+\det(T)\,\text{I}=0$$ for all matrices $T\in\text{Mat}_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{K})$.  With $T:=XZ$ (noting that $\det(X)=\det(Z)=1$), we obtain
$$XZ=\text{Tr}(XZ)\,I-(XZ)^{-1}=\text{Tr}(XZ)\,I-Z^{-1}X^{-1}\,.$$
That is,
$$XYXZ=\text{Tr}(XZ)\,XY-XYZ^{-1}X^{-1}\,.$$
Taking the trace, we get
$$\text{Tr}(XYXZ)=\text{Tr}(XZ)\,\text{Tr}(XY)-\text{Tr}(XYZ^{-1}X^{-1})\,.$$
That is,
$$\text{Tr}(XYXZ)=\text{Tr}(XZ)\,\text{Tr}(XY)-\text{Tr}(YZ^{-1}X^{-1}X)=\text{Tr}(XY)\,\text{Tr}(XZ)-\text{Tr}(YZ^{-1})\,.$$

Comment: If someone downvoted me twice, my reputation would be $23456$.  I'm not even upset if that happens.

Comment: Still more than mine.

Comment: @xpaul  I meant that the number would look very nice if I got two downvotes.  :D  I have been trying to get a screenshot of my reputation if I landed on some nice number.  Always missed.